# How to ignore undefined references (e.g. when temporarily commenting out whole chapters)?

Tags: errors, cross-referencing, pdftex, latexmk, comments

I'm working on a fairly large document, and compilation times are somewhat annoying. My general workflow is to use:

- `latexmk` in continuous mode to compile the document (pdflatex), and
- `rubber-info` on the resulting log file to see warnings/errors.

To speed up the compilation, I would like to comment out major parts of the documents and only compile certain chapters that I'm currently working on. While this solves my issue with the compilation times, it comes with a significant drawback: Obviously, any label of the commented chapters will be missing, resulting in a large number of `Reference ... undefined` errors.

While building the document itself still works, this means that I cannot see all warnings (e.g. overfull boxes etc) of the chapter I'm currently working on -- at least this seems to be the case when using `rubber-info`. Therefore, my question is: Is there a way to tell `latexmk`/`pdflatex` to temporarily ignore undefined references?

Comment: This is exactly what `\include` is for, if you `\include` chapters and then use `\includeonly` to omit them from drafts, cross references into the omitted chapters still work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Good point. The reason I was using `\input` instead of `\include` is because I do not want the added `\clearpage`s, i.e., my file structure does not directly reflect page breaks. Maybe I have to use an intermediate `\include` and group all my `\inputs` into larger chunks...

Comment: @bluenote10 you can see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236029/what-to-input-and-what-to-include-in-a-very-large-document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have refactored my document accordingly, and it seems to be working very well. If you want to convert your comment into an answer I'll accept.

Comment: Unknown references don't raise errors, but only warnings.